# Whitelist an IP in Internal Loadbalancer service GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

We have created a GKE service of type Internal Load balancer. Now we have to whitelist a specific set of IPs outside of VPC network to access that service. How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the GKE Internal Load Balancing [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing):

> Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancing makes your cluster's services accessible to applications outside of your cluster that **use the same VPC network and are located in the same Google Cloud region**.

Therefore, Internal Load Balancer is not accessible externally.

Instead, you can expose your GKE application using [Services](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service) or [Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress) as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/exposing-services-on-gke).
You can find more details on these solutions - [1](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps), [2](https://medium.com/google-cloud/exposing-gke-applications-leveraging-the-built-in-ingress-e87b78e23e90).